# better jsx condition to order component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an icon position prop that decide whether it's placed on the left or on the right of the children. I have this working

```
<List>
    {iconPosition === 'right' && (
        <Text />
    )}
    {icon && (
        <Icon />
    )}
    {iconPosition === 'left' && (
        <Text />
    )}
</List>
```

But I think it can be more simple, although in my opinion my above code is readable.

Comment: Your code is fine and it's the right way

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this any other way. You're using individual conditions with their own result.

Maybe you could place them on one line to make them more readable.

```
<List>
    {iconPosition === 'right' && <Text />}
    {icon && <Icon />}
    {iconPosition === 'left' && <Text />}
</List>
```

or

```
render() {
  const textLeft = (iconPosition === 'left');
  const textRight = (iconPosition === 'right');

  ...
}
```

And use that. But that's mostly down to your preference / the coding style you and your colleagues are using..

Comment: You can actually do this using flex box combined with order css property

Comment: That's correct, but the question was if there's a better JSX-condition approach for this, not if there's a CSS or inline-styilng approach for this.
Otherwise you could simply place a div around `<Text />` and give it a className like ```className={`position--${iconPosition}`}``` and handle it with CSS. But that wasnt the question.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use css float (left/right) but it'll make the icon to be all the way to the right. Another way is to use flex box, take for example:

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
  <div style="flex: 0; order: 1;">(X)</div>
  <div>content</div>
</div>
```

The (X) is the "icon". The `order: 1;` in the style moves it to the right, if you change it to 0 or ommit it, it'll be on the left.

so if you use this approach and put the text + icon in a flex row, all you need to do is:

```
<Icon style={{order: (iconPosition === 'right' ? 1 : 0)}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a higher-order component to attempt to deal with it. It does add some complexity to the project though.

```
const WithConditionalRender = WrappedComponent => (
  ({ renderCondition, ...props }) => {
    if (renderCondition) {
      return <WrappedComponent { ...props } />;
    }

    return null;
  }
);

const ConditionalText = WithConditionalRender(Text);
const ConditionalIcon = WithConditionalRender(Icon);

const Example = ({ icon, iconPosition }) => (
  <List>
    <ConditionalText renderCondition={ iconPosition === 'right' } />
    <ConditionalIcon renderCondition={ icon } />
    <ConditionalText renderCondition={ iconPosition === 'left' } />
  </List>
);
```

This is a generic HOC and could be tweaked to be more specific.